# How do I get placeholder text with javascript on, no placeholder when javascript is off - no HTML5

Tags: javascript, forms

I'd like to have placeholder text while javascript is on by doing something like the following:

```
<input id="firstform" type="text" value="Pizza" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Pizza':this.value;" onfocus="this.select()" onclick="this.value='';" name="firstform">
```

I'd like to have the field blank if javascript is turned off though, as when javascript is off the placeholder text stays when the field is selected.

Unfortunately I can't use the HTML5 placeholder attribute instead of all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the value on page load with JS

```
window.onload = function(){
   document.getElementById('firstform').value = 'Pizza';
};
```

that way if the user has JS off, the field will be blank

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking along those lines, didn't know exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

With javascript turned off, there are very less options, but if you want to consider options with javascript enabled, you can use html5 placeholder and [javascript polyfill](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) for placeholder to make sure it works with and without browsers that supports `placeholder`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply leave the field empty in source and assign the value to it in onload event, which fires only when you have javascript enabled.